# Getting images/videos from XML, displaying each for a certain amount of time

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Here's the concept for this relatively simple Flash app I'm building:

1. Check an XML file on a server.
2. Display content based on  tags, whether type is image or video.
3. Each  has a displayTime value. The content should only stay up for that long, then go on to the next.

So here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<livefeed>

    <timeUpdated string="121213" />

    <content type="image" url='image01.jpg' displayTime="5" />
    <content type="image" url='image02.jpg' displayTime="5" />
    <content type="image" url='image03.jpg' displayTime="5" />

</livefeed>
```

And here's a bit of my ActionScript 3:

```
function onload(e:Event):void {
    var xml:XMLList = new XMLList(xmlholder.data);
    var xmlContent:XMLList = xml.content;
    if(xml.timeUpdated.@string != currentTimeUpdated) {
        currentTimeUpdated = xml.timeUpdated.@string;

        for each (var content:XML in xmlContent) {
            if (content.@type == 'image') {
                var myImageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
                var imageURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(content.@url);

                myImageLoader.load(imageURLRequest);
                myImageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);

                function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {                                
                    var newTimer:Timer = new Timer(content.@displayTime * 1000); // update every 10 seconds
                    newTimer.start();
                    newTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addImage);

                    function addImage(e:TimerEvent):void {
                        addChild(myImageLoader);
                    }

                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it's not working for me as I want it to. I know I'm going about this wrong but not sure how else to do it. I really wanted it to just show the content, pause, go to the next content, pause, then loop.

Any ideas/suggestions on how I should be doing this or how I can improve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this code currently work? You seem to be pilling too much up into a single function - running a bunch of loaders all at once, and using nested functions to deal with the results. I haven't tried it, but it looks a little confused. (I try an stay away from nested functions, btw).

I would break all of this up into a separate chain of functions. You need a sequence that, once the xml has been loaded:

1. initiates the image load
2. responds to the load event
3. then captures the image as loaded data,
4. adds the image into the display list, removing the previously loaded image
5. finally, start a timer, and when it fires, start the sequence up again.

You will need another xml parser / controller function that attends to the image queue - something that just checks the current image count, increments it, and instigate the load sequence again.

You may want to add a couple more steps to run a loading spinner graphic while the load is running, or something, or in some way deal with the interchange from one graphic / video to the next.

Hopefully you've got a grasp on as3 and can figure this out from here. Let me know if you have any hangups. I do have complete classes built out that do exactly all this, and I can share if you need it.

Cheers

**- update -**

> For now, it "works" as in, the script
>   pauses for 5 seconds (with a blank
>   canvas), then displays all the images
>   at once instead of sequentially

This is because you are initiating all your loaders in a single foreach loop, instead of activating individual sequences over time. Definitely not what you want.

**- queue handling -**

So, you have your xml object, which is just a repeated data structure. Importantly, it has a length property, and can be navigated as an index. To traverse this in a chained sequence, you probably need an independent counter variable that you can increment / decrement.

```
private var _count:uint = 0;

private function controlQueue(){

    var target: String = xmlContent[_count].@url; //or however you are obtaining this
    initiateLoad(target);

    _count++: //increment counter

    if(_count > xmlContent.length){ _count = 0}; //if counter exceeds length, swing back around
}

private function initiateLoad(target:String){ ...
```

If you are allowing for user control, then you could pass controlQueue a "direction" argument which could dictate _count++ or _count--;

Pretty simple, but handy.

Hope that helps-

Comment: This Boswoth, I appreciate the advice. For now, it "works" as in, the script pauses for 5 seconds (with a blank canvas), then displays all the images at once instead of sequentially.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of how I might do the image queue?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something very similar. Here is the working code, you can use it as it is or change it. Have Fun!
*Nicholas

By the way, click toggles pause. Unfortunately loadPrevious() is not implemented. Just copy and change the loadNext() Method

Something like this should work. If you want an inverse loop

```
// load Previous
if(__currentIndex>1){
    __currentIndex--;
}else{
    __currentIndex=__xml.child("image").length()-1;
}
```

Here is the Demo Class (How to use ImageSlideshow)

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import de.goldsource.display.ImageSlideshow;

    public class Demo extends Sprite
    {

        public function Demo()
        {

            // setup
            stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align=StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            var xml:XML =   <slideshow>
                                <image src='assets/img1.jpg' delay="0.1" />
                                <image src='assets/img2.jpg' delay="0.1" />
                                <image src='assets/img3.jpg' delay="0.1" />
                            </slideshow>;
            ImageSlideshow.DEBUG = true;
            addChild(new ImageSlideshow(xml));          
        }
    }
}
```

The Slideshow Class. You can use it and change it but keep the license text. The package is de.goldsource.display save this code within a File named ImageSlideshow.as and put it in a directory de/goldsource/display/ relative to your src root or lib.

```
package de.goldsource.display
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.system.System;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;

    /**
     * 
     * <p>
     * <b>License</b>
     * <br/>
     * <a href="http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php">based on The MIT License (MIT)</a>
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * Copyright (c) 2011 Nicholas Schreiber
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @author Nicholas Schreiber
     * */
    public class ImageSlideshow extends Sprite
    {

        /**
         * Traces Memory Usage Info
         * */
        public static var DEBUG:Boolean = false;

        /**
         * Slideshow data
         */
        private var __xml:XML;

        /**
         * Main Timer
         * */
        private var __timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);

        /**
         * True if paused
         * */
        private var __paused:Boolean = false;

        /**
         * Current Element
         * */
        private var __currentIndex:int=-1;


        /**
         * loads the images
         * */
        private var __loader:Loader;

        /**
         * True if Loader has done its job
         * */
        private var __loaderReady:Boolean=true;

        /**
         * Error Count
         * */
        private var __errorCount:uint = 0;

        /**
         * Only for Debug Purposes
         * */
        private var __lastMemoryMax:uint = 0;

        /**
         * ImageSlideshow - Loads and displays Images
         * 
         * <p>
         * jpg, gif or png possible<br/>
         * delay in seconds
         * </p>
         * <p>
         * <code>
         * &lt;slideshow&gt;<br/>
         * &lt;image src='assets/img1.jpg' delay="0.1" /&gt;<br/>
         * &lt;image src='assets/img2.png' delay="2" /&gt;<br/>
         * ...<br/>
         * &lt;image src='assets/imgN.gif' delay="0.1" /&gt;<br/>
         * &lt;/slideshow&gt;<br/>
         * </code>
         * </p> 
         * @param $xml some XML as described above
        * */
        public function ImageSlideshow($xml:XML=null)
        {   
            __xml = $xml;       
            __loader = new Loader();

            // Click toggles Pause
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,__onClick);

            // The Update Interval
            __timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,__onTimer);

            // load the first image
            loadNext();
        }

        /**
         * Toggle Pause
         * */
        public function togglePause():void{
            if(__paused){
                __paused = false;
            }else{                              
                __paused = true;
            }
            __updateTimerStatus();
        }

        /**
         * loadNext Image (looped)
         * */
        public function loadNext():void{            
            // return if not possible
            if(!__loaderReady || __xml == null)return;  

            // loader is blocked
            __loaderReady = false;  

            // load Next
            if(__currentIndex<__xml.child("image").length()-1){
                // slides availabe
                __currentIndex++;
            }else{
                // no more slides, looping the slideshow...
                __currentIndex=0;
            }   

            // resetting timer
            __timer.stop();
            __timer.reset();
            // setting delay
            __timer.delay = __xml.child("image")[__currentIndex].@delay*1000;

            // setup loader
            __loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, __onLoadComplete);
            __loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,__onIOError);

            // load
            __loader.load(new URLRequest(__xml.child("image")[__currentIndex].@src));               
        }

        /**
         * toggles Pause on Click
         * */       
        private function __onClick($e:MouseEvent):void{
            togglePause();
        }

        /**
         * starts the timer if possible or stops it if paused
         * */
        private function __updateTimerStatus():void{    
            if(!__loaderReady)return;
            if(__paused && __timer.running){
                __timer.stop();
            }else{                              
                __timer.start();
            }

        }

        /**
         * Invoked by the timer
         * */
        private function __onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void{
            loadNext();
        }       

        /**
         * Invoked if image is not existent (wrong src url!)
         * */
        private function __onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void{          
            // remove listeners
            __loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, __onLoadComplete);   
            __loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,__onIOError);                      

            // iterate error count, will stop the app when > 10 in a row
            __errorCount ++;            
            trace("Image could not be loaded "+__errorCount +" of 10 attempts");


            if(__errorCount > 10)return;

            // if more than one image in list try next
            __loaderReady = true;
            if(__xml.child("image").length()>1)loadNext();          
        }

        /**
         * Invoked when image is loaded
         * */
        private function __onLoadComplete(e:Event):void{    
            // remove the listeners
            __loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, __onLoadComplete);   
            __loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,__onIOError);

            // reset the error count, cause on image was loaded successful
            __errorCount = 0;

            // add the loaded image to the display
            addChild(__loader.content); 

            // yes the loader is no longer blocked
            __loaderReady = true;

            // restarts the timer if was running
            __updateTimerStatus();

            // removes 
            __cleanUp();
        }

        /**
         * Removes all unnecessary Bitmaps
         * */
        private function __cleanUp():void{
            // leave method if nothing to do (only one object on screen)
            if(numChildren==1)return;   

            /*  
                never forget to dispose() a bitmap you want to get rid of,
                otherwise FlashPlayer will not remove it from the RAM
                removing and disposing within one line
            */
            if(getChildAt(0) is Bitmap)Bitmap(removeChildAt(0)).bitmapData.dispose();

            // Debug mode only
            if(!DEBUG)return;
            if(__lastMemoryMax<System.totalMemory){
                trace("New Memory Peak "+((__lastMemoryMax= System.totalMemory)/Math.pow(1024,2)).toFixed(2)+" MB");
            }           
        }

        /**
         * xml Getter / Setter - Slideshow data
         * <p>
         * jpg, gif or png possible<br/>
         * delay in seconds
         * </p>
         * <p>
         * <code>
         * &lt;slideshow&gt;<br/>
         * &lt;image src='assets/img1.jpg' delay="0.1" /&gt;<br/>
         * &lt;image src='assets/img2.png' delay="2" /&gt;<br/>
         * ...<br/>
         * &lt;image src='assets/imgN.gif' delay="0.1" /&gt;<br/>
         * &lt;/slideshow&gt;<br/>
         * </code>
         * </p>
         * 
         * @param value XML
         * @return XML
         * */
        public function get xml():XML
        {
            return __xml;
        }

        public function set xml(value:XML):void
        {
            __xml = value;
            __currentIndex = -1;
            loadNext();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks! I'll give it a shot. The only issue I may have is that some of the items in my XML will be videos, not just images. I'll play around with it.

Comment: I'm using your script as-is, but I'm getting the following error. The first image is displayed, then right after the delay time, this is the error: http://i.imgur.com/sfiCy.png

Comment: Hi dallen, which IDE do you use? I wrote it within FlashBuilder and tested it with FlashCS5, works fine for me. I've seen this error before, when trying to remove some child that did not exist using the removeChild() method. Can you post your xml and the class, where you add the slideshow?

Comment: Just uploaded an archive to http://public.goldsource.de/stackOverflow/ImageSlideshow.zip contains FlashCS5 Project & FlashBuilder Project. I am out for lunch, really hungry now, will be back in a hour or two. Hope it works using the source within the archive.

Comment: Shoot. I should have tried this first. I was working in Flash CS3 on my old Mac. When I brought it over to my laptop with CS5.5, it works like a charm. Thanks goldsource, I really appreciate this.

Comment: You're welcome! You wrote that you want to playback video and stuff. Even if it's not the best way, you can do so by loading swf files containing a video player or anything else. You have to change the __cleanUp method 'if(getChildAt(0) is Bitmap){ Bitmap(removeChildAt(0)).bitmapData.dispose();}else if(getChildAt(0) is MovieClip){delete MovieClip(removeChildAt(0))};' to remove and  delete a MovieClip.

Comment: Did it work for you? I've just seen the thread is still open.